# SDI Onboard SDK PositionData incorrect latitude longitude from simulator

Tags: dji-sdk

We're using the DJI Assistant 2 as the similator, a linux machine as the onboard computer, and we're not getting the correct latitude and longitude out from PositionData.

```
PositionData p = api->getBroadcastData().pos;
std::cout << "LAT:" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << p.latitude << endl;
std::cout << "LONG:" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << p.longitude << endl;
```

I've set the simulator to start at lat=1.0 and long=2.0.  The position data I get back from the above code is:

```
LAT:0.01745329
LONG:0.03490660
```

Height/altitude seem to come out correctly, just the latitude/longitude seem incorrect.

I've tried a range of lat/long settings in the simulator, but it still doesn't seem to be accurate.  The lat/long always seems to be < 1.

Am I missing something incredibly obvious?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

the values you see in BroadcastData are in radians; you'll need to convert to degrees to see the values you are setting.

Comment: Thanks!  That's it.

Comment: And when setting waypoint lat/long I use radians as well I assume?